# how to filter a file to get lines that consist entirely of pairs of repeated digits?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have file that has numbers starting from

```
00000000
00000001
00000002
.
.
.
99999999
```

I want to filter it in bash so that the output is like this:

```
00000000
00000011
00000022
.
.
11223344
11223355
.
.
99999977
99999988
99999999
```

Comment: What is your question? I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: It looks like you want to *filter* lines that consist entirely of pairs of repeated digits, rather than sort the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you actually want to *filter* the file rather than sort it - in particular, to output only those lines that consist entirely of pairs of repeated characters or (more specifically) digits. So for example using `grep`, something like

```
grep -Ex '((.)\2)+' yourfile
```

or using PCRE mode to avoid capturing the outer group

```
grep -Px '(?:(\d)\1)+' yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your numbers have eight digits and are in a file called nums.txt,  you can use the awk string function of substr to filter in all the lines whose last two characters are the same:

```
awk '{ if(substr($1, 7, 1)==substr($1, 8, 1)) print $1}' nums.txt
```

You then get:

```
    00000000
    00000011
    00000022
    00000055

....
```